# hopscotch game in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve this question for 2 days but unable to solve it, gets really frustrated.
I hope anyone can help me to get rid out of this problem.

Write a program for given an integer list where each number represents the number of hops you can make in hopscotch game, determine whether you can reach to the last index starting at index 0.

For example, [2, 0, 1, 0] returns True while [1, 1, 0, 1] returns False.

Input Format

single line space separated integers

Constraints

len(list) > 0

Output Format

Boolean True or False

Sample Input 0

```
2 3 1 1 4
```

Sample Output 0

```
True
```

Explanation 0

Input: nums = [2,3,1,1,4]
Output: True
Explanation: Jump 1 step from index 0 to 1, then 3 steps to the last index.
Sample Input 1

```
3 2 1 0 4
```

Sample Output 1

```
False
```

Explanation 1

Input: nums = [3,2,1,0,4]
Output: False
Explanation: You will always arrive at index 3 no matter what. Its maximum jump length is 0, which makes it impossible to reach the last index.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, can you clarify?

Comment: @Fgr It looks like you [got the problem from Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/). It would be nice if you would have included a link to the source of your question so that, at the very least, we can see an easier to read and easier to understand version of your question.

Comment: @Fgr By the way, since this question is up on Leetcode, you can simply look at the "discuss" tab to find different solutions to the problem (I recommend sorting by votes). I'd recommend that you pick your favorite approach, try to understand it, and if you can't understand it then ask a new question here about the specific approach that you are trying to understand

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understood the question correctly, this should be the solution:

```
sample1 = [2,3,1,1,4]
sample2 = [3,2,1,0,4]

def hopscotch(sample):
    last_index = len(sample) - 1
    current_index = 0
    while True:
        if current_index == last_index:
            return True
        elif current_index > last_index:
            return False #Or True depending on if you can hop off the end
        elif sample[current_index] == 0:
            return False
        else:
            current_index += sample[current_index]
```

Just increase the index by the value at that index and check if you are at the end of the list, over the end of the list or the current element is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can find optimum solutions at **Solutions** section in Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/solutions/